# GridView PageIndexChanging forcing me to "search" again to move to the next page.

Tags: .net, gridview

I have a DataTable that is returned from a stored Procedure and am displaying the data in a GridView When data is returned, I see the number of pages of data, but when I select a page, it reloads and no data is displayed. Then, if I select the Search button again, I get the data for the correct page. Am I missing a step here? My code is below. Thank you.

```
     protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = DataLayer.PricingToolDL.PriceSearch(brandCode, brandName, item, ownerCode, ownerName, color, billTo, shipTo, customerName, status);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

My GridView code looks like this.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="True" onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging">
```

My GridView1_PageIndexChanging method looks like this.

```
    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rebind the DataSource. I would create a new method like this:

```
private void BindGrid()
{
    GridView1.DataSource = {{your data source}}
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Then, call this method from your paging event handler, like this:

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindGrid();
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you. Though I feel like I am pinging my database more often this way.

Comment: You can cache your datasource to resolve that issue. Depending on its size and the performance of your application/db, it might make sense to do so.